# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'

Tags: python, pychart

I want to get a PDF file, but I get an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'`. The error says that `can` doesn't have the attribute `show`. Why? As you can see, I import `show` from `pychart.canvas`.

```
from pychart import *
from pychart.canvas import show
can = canvas.init("pic.pdf")
x, y = (100, 500)

def show_text(str):
    global x, y
    can.show(x, y, str)
    can.show(x + 200, y, "/12/C" + font.quotemeta(str))
    y -= 20

show_text("/12/hLLeft align")
show_text("/12/hRRight align")
show_text("/12/hCCenter align")
show_text("/a20/12/hRAngled text")

def show_textv(str):
    global x, y
    can.show(x, y, str)
    x += 150

y -= 40
x = 100
show_textv("/12/vT//12//vTTop align")
show_textv("/12/vM//12//vT/12Middle align")
show_textv("/12/vB//12//vT/12Bottom align")

y -= 40
x = 100
show_text("/16/HHelvetica")
show_text("/12/CCourier")
show_text("/12/NHelvetica-Narrow")
show_text("/12/PPalatino-Roman")
show_text("/12/AAvantgarde")
show_text("/12/T/iTimes-Italic")
show_text("/12/F{ZapfDingbats}ZapfDingbats")
```

Comment: No, the error means that `can` is None.

Comment: Is that all of your code?  What line does the error occur on?  Glancing at the pychart documentation, it doesn't look like `canvas.init` should ever return `None`, which is what appears to be happening from what you have given us.  Also, is there a reason you are importing `pychart.canvas.show` - you don't appear to be using it anywhere.

Comment: The line where the error occurs on as follows:File "C:\Users\wangling\Desktop\pdf6.py", line 8, in show_text
    can.show(x, y, str)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'

Comment: @wangling: what value is `canvas.init(...)` returning on line 3?

Answer (score 0):

NoneType is type of None object.
When can == None and you call following:

```
can.show(x, y, str)
```

you actually call None.show(x, y, str) and get AttributeError, because None doesn't have 'show' attribute

To fix your problem try to investigate why can == None